# How to make cmd commands using python

Tags: python, cmd

Is there any way to make a custom cmd command using python? So when I type this in command prompt-

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.867]
(c) 2020 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:/Users/User123>command1
```

I can make the prompt show "Hello World!" like this-

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.867]
(c) 2020 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:/Users/User123>command1

C:/Users/User123>Hello World!
```

Answer (score 1):

I Think you can do it by, declaring a variable in your environment. and set your python script to that variable.

Comment: I don't understand, could you give a code example please?

Comment: Are you looking into converting your `.py` file to an executable file? In that case, you can use pyinstaller: `pip install pyinstaller` and for further information refer to the sources of the module: https://datatofish.com/executable-pyinstaller/